# Saving an EKCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, software-design, eventkit

Once you create an EKCalendar, it's often said that you should hold onto the calendarIdentifier to retrieve that calendar later.  However, the documentation notes that the identifier will change if/when a full calendar sync is performed and "you should have a plan" to deal with that.

What would be the preferred or "standard" method of handling this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation

> A full sync with the calendar will lose this identifier. You should have a plan for dealing with a calendar whose identifier is no longer fetch-able by caching its other properties.

Not sure if there is any "standard" way of handling it. But keeping the identifier of its `source` is one way of handling it. The `sourceIdentifier` does not change once the calendar is created and the calendar cannot be moved to a different source.

Comment: But the sourceIdentifier is the same for all calendars that belong to that source... I'm not sure how that would help in retrieving the specific calendar, as you'd retrieve any number of calendars, of the same source, right?